# websocket reconnect on close with code 1006

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am using javascript websocket and want it to reconnect onclose with code 1006.
I came across this

[Reconnection of Client when server reboots in WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780511/reconnection-of-client-when-server-reboots-in-websocket)

the accepted answer there does work but after 20 seconds when the server reconnects the number of attempted connections rise to 4 and the user receives 4 messages which was actually sent only once.

The 20 seconds is just a number, the loss of connection could be server side issue or a client internet issue.

I hope I have been clear in describing the issue
Regards,
Shyam

Answer (score 1):

You can watch on your close event error code and reconnect

```
var ws = null; //reserve it for websocket

function connectWebsocket(){ 
    if ("WebSocket" in window) //browser supports webscokets
    {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://your_url");
        ws.addEventListener("open", socketOpened);
        ws.addEventListener("message", messageRecived);
        ws.addEventListener("close", socketClosed);
     }else // browser doesn't support chat.. 
     {
        alert("Websockets not supported by browser ");
     }
 };
 function socketClosed(evt){ 
       switch(evt.code){
            case 1006: 
                setTimeout(connectWebsocket,1000); //try to reconnect in 1s
                break;

        }
   };
```